# How to decorate a conditional statement to be an expression?

Tags: c++, c

I want to use condition statement as an expression, such as below, how to make it?

```
0, (do {a++;} while (a > 100););
```

**EDIT**, the reason I want to do this is I want to add a conditional statement to an existing expression for debugging purpose, the existing expression is in a header file and included by many source files. For example, I want to write some debug message when the previous expression reaches some special value.

Comment: Can you give more explanation?

Comment: Even if you could do this, I'd hurt you for doing it.

Comment: Do you feel that your code is not sufficiently obfuscated and can still be easily read by other programmers? Or are you under the misguided notion that cramming more instructions into fewer lines of code will make your program magically run faster?

Comment: @Thomson: I'm trying to follow the explanation in your EDIT... you have an expression in a header file?  As in `#define EXPR ++x + 2 * y` or something, with client code ala `fn(EXPR)`?  If so, maybe you can change EXPR with a call to a function?

Comment: @Tony, you are right, put the extra expression at the end of the previous one will have some side effect in some cases(such as yours), I can put the extra exp to the front of the previous expression in that case. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Thomson: It's usually best to surround a macro substitution with parentheses ala `(++x + 2 * y)`, though if that wasn't already done there's there's a small chance it may "fix" some existing "bugs", intended or otherwise. If you modify it perhaps `(fn(), ++x + 2 * y)`, or `(fn(++x + 2 * y))` where you write `fn` to return its argument.  If helpful and `x`, `y` or whatever aren't local to the calling scopes/objects etc. then they can be moved inside `fn()`.

Answer (score 4):

You simply can't have a `do-while` statement inside an expression in Standard C++ (there's a GCC-specific extension http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).  But what are you really trying to achieve? - we may be able to find an elegant alternative...

In C++0x, you can get close, ala...

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    std::cout << (([&]() -> int { do { a--; } while (a > 10); return a; })()) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You must specify a lambda's return type when it consists of more than a single return statement, otherwise the return type is void. (N3225 §5.1.2p4)

Comment: @Fred: good point... strange GCC 4.5.2 didn't complain :-/.  Fixed above... thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just put it in an `inline` function. This works for C++ as well as for C99. If you have special things that should evaluate at the place of the caller, wrap the call into a macro that does exactly the evaluations that you need.

Answer (score 2):

> the reason I want to do this is I want to add a conditional statement to an existing expression for debugging purpose, the existing expression is in a header file and included by many source files. For example, I want to write some debug message when the previous expression reaches some special value.

Use a function.  Mark it inline if you want to define it in the header.